# What happens with No-Maj-Borns?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts

In the *Harry Potter* series, lots of Muggle parents are introduced to the wizarding world because of their magical children. This is seen with Hermione's parents visiting Diagon Alley and various other moments.

In the 1920s USA world that has been created, rules about fraternising with No-Majs are very strict. Is there any evidence in any of the Pottermore articles or recently published film tie-ins which explain what happens with magical children born to No-Majs around this time? (Clearly certain events in the film suggest that they may have no procedure and that there can be side-effects of this - but I feel that those events must be rare!)

Comment: Murdered and ground up into No-Maj hotdogs, served at Quodpot matches.

Answer (score 14):

No-Maj-born witches and wizards are integrated into Wizarding society. No mention is made of their families, but presumably they're separated from them at an early age and the families obliviated to remove any knowledge of Wizardkind.

Per *Pottermore*:

> Pure-blood families, who were well-informed through wizarding
> newspapers about the activities of both Puritans and Scourers, rarely
> left for America. **This meant a far higher percentage of No-Maj-born
> witches and wizards in the New World than elsewhere.**
>
> **While these witches and wizards often went on to marry and found their
> own all-magical families, the pure-blood ideology that has dogged much
> of Europe’s magical history has gained far less traction in America.**
>
> <sub><sup>[History of Magic in North America](https://www.pottermore.com/collection-episodic/history-of-magic-in-north-america-en)</sup></sub>

We're also told that the split between Wizard and No-Maj society is absolute, with ***zero exceptions***.

> Dorcus’s indiscretions led to the introduction of Rappaport’s Law.
> **Rappaport’s Law enforced strict segregation between the No-Maj and
> wizarding communities.**
>
> Wizards were no longer allowed to befriend or marry No-Majs. Penalties
> for fraternising with No-Majs were harsh. **Communication with No-Majs
> was limited to that necessary to perform daily activities.**

Again, this presumably extends to family members.

Comment: That's quite dark. Any chance do we think of a Professor X sort of arrangement? Parents saying "I thought he went to a school for the gifted!" ?

Comment: @ThruGog - Why take the risk? When you live in a world where memory charms are easy and 100% effective, why not use them?

Comment: Permanent separation of children and their parents springs to mind quite quickly!

Comment: @Thrugog - it worked for the Jedi.

Comment: @Valorum it worked for [Janissaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Janissaries). Speaking about Jedi, there should be some age limit after which indoctrination is less likely and these wiz-kids are not taken into wizarding society.

Comment: Both of you speak of an order that requires great discipline because a) there is a risk that attachment lures to the dark side and b) some selfish sultan demands it. These are not issues in this world. I suspect that you @Valorum are correct, but it is pretty dark!

Comment: @Valorum The issue would not be the parents, but the No-Maj-Borns themselves. Are we saying that *every* American No-Maj-Born is willing to sacrifice his or her family for the good of the community without protest or resistance? That seems wildly inhuman, let alone un-American.

Comment: @deworde - Laws are laws. The statutes seem quite clear.

Comment: @Valorum Yes, but no popular/political resistance to it? Or simply de facto disobedience? Seems improbable.

Comment: @deworde - They have an entire dept of their ministry devoted to obliviating No-Maj's who come into any contact with wizards and wizards themselves are jailed for not obliviating any No-Maj's that happen to see magic. I doubt if family are exempted.

Comment: @Valorum So there's no protest at familial separation among No-Maj-borns? The act of separating 11 year old children from their parents is considered non-controversial? Troubling.

Comment: @deworde - They did it in 1950s China with relatively few complaints

Comment: I'm not sure how much relevance the top quote has. Given the introduction of Rappaport’s would suggest a significant change in attitude. It might still be open and welcoming to muggle-borns, but mixed children would be specifically illegal which is likely to have an effect on attitudes.

Answer (score 4):

This is one of the troubling consequences of the law, which hopefully someone will raise with Rowling at some point (or possibly the films themselves will raise).

Most probably the solution is that they are supposed to keep their powers secret from their parents, with Obliviation used as a tool in this.

In reality, I suspect an attitude of "Don't Ask, Don't Tell" applies, where unless it becomes likely that their parents will expose the community, no-one in the Ministry digs that deeply into how hard that particular separation is maintained.

Most of the other solutions are somewhat [horrifying](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/145924/2213), although given MECUSA can apparently execute members of the community without due process, I wouldn't be suprised to find out they're used.

Answer (score -1):

I would like to remind everyone that this was a philosophy and law that began in 1790 and was repealed in 1965. Undoubtedly, since the S.o.S. began in 1692-93, almost a century before hand, and that MACUSA began (likely under a different name, like "Magical Congress of North America" or some such, since the U.S. didn't exist in that time) the same year the S.o.S. was established, MACUSA likely had laws dealing with these situations.

The most likely and reasonable would be introduction of the parents to the magical community on a temporary basis to test if they could be trusted to keep it secret, with obliviation of the knowledge of magic and their child should they prove they cannot. Rappaport's law, however, forced them into an "act now, (reversible memory charm) can we trust them (observe and report) later" approach, regrettably. In all likelihood, all reports during this time came back as "Parents untrustworthy with the Secret of Wizardkind."

Since the repeal of Rappaport's law, however, after two centuries nearly of total isolation from their no-maj counterparts, it is entirely likely the Rappaport's Law era law's concerning no-maj parent's continued and took some HEAVY and staunch activism to have those law's repealed over time. I see the law's and social outlook in the area of No-maj parents from 1965 to the 1990's and on to today in the same as that era's improvements concerning inter-racial marriage among no-maj's during this time. Disconcerting by today's standards by far, but always ever improving and progressing.

It is my belief, if I may give it, that the relationship of no-maj born's, and their parents specifically, with the magical communities in America is actually a euphemism  for the outlook on inter-racial marriages by American society.

However, all of this is conjecture. It is still unknown, by J. K. Rowling's Canon, if there even is a way for Ilvermorny or MACUSA to know when a Magical child is born! The quill and book Hogwarts uses could, POSSIBLY, be used, but that would mean only one institution in the whole world would have direct access to the knowledge base that is the future of the wizarding world. This is an unlikely scenario as it states that this is the only method for a student to be accepted into HOGWARTS. It is also said that this book and quill had not been touched by human hand since the founders, and, from what I can see a lot of the known magic during that time has since been lost.

To sum it up, the answer is... Rowling has yet to answer this specific question, and until she does (which is seeming less likely as the years pass that she will) it is best for you to find your own answer, as much as that may suck.

Comment: This all seems like guesswork. Can you offer any actual evidence to support it?